# PHPUnit coverage: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, docker, phpunit, phpdbg

I am trying to generate code test coverage for my PHP project with PHPUnit and phpdbg using the following command:

```
phpdbg -dmemory_limit=512M -qrr ./bin/phpunit -c .phpunit.cover.xml
```

This works perfectly fine:

```
PHPUnit 6.2.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

........                                                            8 / 8 (100%)

Time: 114 ms, Memory: 14.00MB

OK (8 tests, 13 assertions)

Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done
```

However, when I use the exact same command in a docker container:

```
docker run -it --name YM4UPltmiPMjObaVULwsIPIkPL2bGL0T -e USER=sasan -v "/home/sasan/Project/phpredmin:/phpredmin" -w "/phpredmin" --user "1000:www-data" php:7.0-apache phpdbg -dmemory_limit=512M -qrr ./bin/phpunit -c .phpunit.cover.xml
```

I get the following error:

```
PHPUnit 6.2.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

[PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 561514763337856 bytes) in /phpredmin/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/GlobalState.php on line 166]
```

I don't understand why PHPUnit needs to allocate 561514763337856 bytes of memory. I suspect it gets stuck in a loop, but why this does not happen outside of the container? Here is my PHP version on my machine:

```
PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 (cli) (built: Aug  8 2017 22:03:30) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.22-0ubuntu0.17.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

And here is the .phpunit.cover.xml file:

```
<phpunit
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/6.3/phpunit.xsd"
        backupGlobals="false"
        backupStaticAttributes="false"
        bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
        cacheTokens="false"
        colors="false"
        convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
        convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
        convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
        processIsolation="false"
        stopOnError="true"
        stopOnFailure="true"
        stopOnIncomplete="false"
        stopOnSkipped="false"
        stopOnRisky="false"
        timeoutForSmallTests="1"
        timeoutForMediumTests="10"
        timeoutForLargeTests="60"
        verbose="false">
    <testsuites>
            <testsuite name="PhpRedmin PHP source">
            <directory>src-test/</directory>
            </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="cover/" lowUpperBound="35" 
highLowerBound="70"/>
    </logging>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src-test/</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">src/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

**-- Edit1 --**

I found that it has something to do with @runInSeparateProcess. When I remove the test that has @runInSeparateProcess then it starts to work. But still I don't know what is the problem

**-- Edit2 --**

Also I found out that If I don't mount my code directory in the Docker container everything works fine

Comment: What docker image are you using? is php as service or as a apache module? , try to increase the php memory in php.ini

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: @JoaquinJavi As you can see it's **php:7.0-apache**:
    docker run -it --name YM4UPltmiPMjObaVULwsIPIkPL2bGL0T -e USER=sasan -v "/home/sasan/Project/phpredmin:/phpredmin" -w "/phpredmin" --user "1000:www-data" **php:7.0-apache** phpdbg -dmemory_limit=512M -qrr ./bin/phpunit -c .phpunit.cover.xml

I can't increase my memory limit to 561514763337856 bytes

Comment: @TarunLalwani

     PHP **7.0.22-0ubuntu0.17.04.1** (cli) (built: Aug  8 2017 22:03:30) ( NTS )

So it's ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Try without `--user "1000:www-data"` and see if it helps

Comment: @TarunLalwani No change

Comment: Phpunit will analyze the file is it able to get to the path, if not it will just ignore it and create the report. See if that is something that is changed between host and container

Comment: @TarunLalwani no that's not the case

Comment: Can't say much without having a sample code to try

Comment: Try without `php:7.0-apache` go normal `php`.

Comment: @Daredzik no change

Comment: Can you provide a git repo with minimum example which I can use to reproduce this?

Answer (score 16):

Add '-d memory_limit=-1' before your test

if use composer use the below code

```
./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit -d memory_limit=-1 tests/
```

if you use phpdbg use the below code

```
phpdbg -d memory_limit=-1 -qrr vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text
```

Comment: I had assumed a bug in `phpdbg` or a recursive loop in my code that manifests only when testing, but, alas, the solution was exactly as you describe: `phpdbg` just needed more memory! I had to double the 128M default and use 256M (I don't like the idea of using unlimited).

Answer (score 7):

When we use `@runInSeparateProcess`, PHPUnit will attempt to serialize included files, ini settings, global variables, and constants to pass them to the new process. In this case, it looks like PHPUnit encountered a recursive scenario when serializing one of these items, which exhausted the memory available to the PHP process. We need to determine what changed between your local environment and the Docker container.

First, we can try disabling this serialization behavior to verify that we should proceed along this path. Add the following `@preserveGlobalState` annotation to the test method that fails:

```
/**
 * @runInSeparateProcess
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 */
public function testInSeparateProcess()
{
    // ...
}
```

If this resolves the problem, or if we get a new error, we can begin looking for differences in the Docker container that may cause the issue. Without more visibility into the code and environment, it's hard to suggest where to start, but here are some ideas:

- Compare the output of `php -i` from each environment. Look out for PHP extensions that exist in one, but not the other.
- Use `phpdbg` to set a breakpoint and step through the code. We're already using it to generate coverage, but it's also a useful debugging tool. We're looking for the item that causes the infinite recursion. Note that we'll need to set the breakpoint *before* PHPUnit executes the test case such as in the bootstrap file or PHPUnit source code (line 810 of `TestCase` may work).
- When bind-mounting a volume, make sure the `www-data` user in the container has the same UID as the user that owns the files on the host.
- Try running the test without the memory limitation. Obviously we can't allocate as much as the error suggests we may need, but the memory limit may mask another underlying problem. We can kill the container if needed.

I couldn't reproduce this issue using a dummy test in a similar environment (as close as I could get—same container with volume), so the code under test may contribute to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your mounted folder probably has all vendors and cache files. Try mounting only the source folder.

Comment: But all the phpunit files and thirdparty files needed in my tests are in vendors. What's point of not mounting them?

Comment: you can still access vendors and phpunit. The volume is sort of a symlink to the files meaning the changes to those files will be persisted even after container is stopped. you can try it with this `docker run -it --name YM4UPltmiPMjObaVULwsIPIkPL2bGL0T -e USER=sasan -v "/home/sasan/Project/phpredmin/src:/phpredmin/src" -w "/phpredmin" --user "1000:www-data" php:7.0-apache phpdbg -dmemory_limit=512M -qrr ./bin/phpunit -c .phpunit.cover.xml
`  https://docs.docker.com/glossary/?term=volume

Answer (score 0):

This is phpdbg bug. Note how much memory it tries to allocate? It is insane. I tried hard to figure out where the bug exactly: if test script full name (directory + script file name) exceeds certain size then it overflows the stack (yeah, stackoverflow ;) and overwrites integer which specifies how much memory must be allocated. Then normal error handling kicks in: not enough memory to allocate such insane amount. So this is for Krakjoe to fix. Or may be I will make a patch for it in my spare time. If you need to have resolution right now: make sure that directory path your script is in is short.